# Access webhook information from Dialogflow in Django

Tags: django, request, dialogflow-es

I have configured Dialogflow to make a POST request after a name is asked. When I view the information in an online request viewer I can see the information I want in the Query strings section:

```
> {   "responseId": "045c0d0b-7b5b-448e...",  
> "queryResult": {
>     "queryText": "rob",
>     "parameters": {
>       "last-name": "lastname",
>       "given-name": "Rob"
>     },
```

In Django however, I cannot find this information. I tried to save the full request and request.META in the database.

The received request on my server looks like:

> {'QUERY_STRING': '', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'CONTENT_TYPE':
>   'application/json', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '5323', 'REQUEST_URI':
>   '/folder', 'PATH_INFO': '/folder', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT':
>   '/home/info/domains/mysite.info/private_html', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL':
>   'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTPS': 'on', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '64.233.172.250',
>   'REMOTE_PORT': '53451', 'SERVER_PORT': '443', 'SERVER_NAME':
>   'mysite.info', 'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json', 'HTTP_HOST':
>   'www.mysite.info', 'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': '5323', 'HTTP_CONNECTION':
>   'keep-alive', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT':
>   'Google-Dialogflow', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,br',
>   'wsgi.input': ,
>   'wsgi.file_wrapper': ,
>   'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2
>   mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>, 'wsgi.run_once': False,
>   'wsgi.multithread': False, 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
>   'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https', 'uwsgi.version': b'2.0.18', 'uwsgi.node':
>   b'server.mysite.info', 'SCRIPT_NAME': ''}

I use Nginx with Uwsgi

How do I access the full information in Django?

Answer (score 0):

I should have used request.body in the view. There is no need to use custom headers in Dialogflow. All needed information is in the request.